# Выбор файловой системы для раздела сервера

Tags: windows-7, linux

Здравствуйте. Занимаюсь (недолго) веб-разработкой. На компе стоят Win7 и Linux Mint 13. Решил сделать отдельный раздел для сервера и настроить apache на винде и линухе на этот раздел. Собственно, возник вопрос: какую файловую систему выбрать, чтоб и винда видела (ext4 отпадает) и линух нормально работал и мог примонтировать его? NTFS или FAT подойдет для этих целей?
П.С. Может идея совсем глупая и сделать, чтоб на линуксе со своей работал, а винда со своей? Просто думаю перейти полностью на линукс, но в винду иногда тоже придется заглядывать. И хранение проектов в одном месте было полезным

Comment: почему "ext4 отпадает"?

Comment: @ArcherGodson, а как винду подружить с ext4 ? Никогда таким не занимался

Answer (score 1):

Идея глупая, делайте отдельно.

p.s. linux без проблем примонтирует ntfs разделы когда надо, windows при желании тоже может монтировать `ext2\ext3 - http://www.ext2fsd.com/`

Comment: @Anton Shevtsov, аргументировать сможете? Пока: Плюсы:  1. Проекты хранятся в одном месте и доступны серверу и на лине и на винде;  2. При переустановки оси (любой) все проекты останутся нетронутыми;  Минусы:  ???

Comment: ntfs\fat чужеродные системы, они не поддерживают аттрибутов linux. Это тоже самое что на машину поставить восьмиугольные колеса - ехать будет, но медленно и не комфортно. А в итоге все развалиться.

Comment: единственная проблема с fat - отсутствие возможности управлять правами на файлы средствами файловой системы. в ntfs тож как этим управлять я хз, но если комп локальный и для веб-разработки - то это абсолютно пофиг с точки зрения "чужеродности" и производительности, просто правами нужно будет управлять через веб-сервер, а при передаче в продакшн не забыть переопределить атрибуты файлов на безопасные.

Answer (score 1):

А кто мешает зеркалить сайт с одной файловой системы на другую? И если сайт под Линем работает - то юзать Ext4, а под Вендами - NTFS? Кстати, обе системы журналируемые. Единственный минус - это уменьшает свободное дисковое пространство. Плюс - повышает надёжность, если Ext4 и NTFS на разных физических дисках.

Comment: @areshin, хм. Интересное решение. Если я правильно понял, просто хранить одни файлы на разных дисках. Надо подумать когда зеркалить. Было бы логичным, например, при выходе из линя копировать все в NTFS. И наоброт. Чем бы только это сделать, чтоб автоматизировать процесс, не подскажете? Можно конечно самому написать, но времени жалко.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужна совместимость с Windows то я бы использовал NTFS. Только вот нужна ли она? По моему Apache и Linux идеальная пара:)

Comment: @Семен Ледовский, согласен, но от винды полностью тоже не откажешься( Например, к серверу по webdav не смог подключиться, а винде удобный клиент webdav. Eще не могу отвыкнуть от dbForge Studio, точнее от построения диаграмм БД, Punto Switcher (XNeur далеко до него), Total Commander RIP и т.д.((  П.С. Буду пробовать решить эти проблемы через VirtualBox, но что-то мне подсказывает, что будет не все так просто...

Comment: Я отказался! По webdav подключаюсь через Nautilus, очень удобно. Virtualbox не плохо.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую использовать NTFS или ext3. В случае с ext3 нужно будет установить под Windows драйвер ext2fsd и создать перманентные маунты для интересующих разделов ext3.По поводу совместимости драйверов с win7/8 - у меня на машине ext2fsd-0.51 успешно работает на Win7-x64.

Comment: Я бы не советовал ставить Ext*, т.к. все драйвера которые есть без подписи, и поэтому рано или поздно Вы можете столкнуться с проблемой их загрузки на Win x64 (7-ка или 8-ка).А с NTFS линух давно хорошо дружит.

Answer (score 0):

Just use git ...

PS: А вот правда интересно, зачем на винде-то Apache поднимать?

Comment: Он девелопер, сидит на винде, где-то нужно запускать и дебажить проекты

Comment: Смотря как и что дебажить, в любом случае виртуалка с Виндой решает. Хотя, если продакшн будет на винде ...

Comment: ничего критичного, я тут человечка знаю одного (думаю он не один), что вполне, может "не серьёзный", но "денежный" проект именно на винде, и сползать с него не собирется вообще )) так что вот